# How can I change State when an Event is triggered with useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

to learn react im trying to implement a basic shop.

My Idea was to have many product-images. If an user clicks on an product-image this image turns around and shows something like comments, rating, etc of the product.

For this question i have 3 js Files:
Container.js (contains everything from the product-cards to navbar etc),
ProductList.js (returns the UL with all the different Products) and ItemCard.js (returns the actual product as LI ).

My Goal is to just invert the backsideVisible value.

I provide an minimal example for better understanding:

Container.js:

```
function Container() {
    const [item, setItem] = useState([{
        title: "some product title",
        price: "14.99$",
        backsideVisible: false
        id: 1
    }]);

    function handleTurn(event, itemId) {
        //here i want to change the backsideVisible value
        event.preventDefault();
        setItem(item.map(item => {
            if(item.id === itemId) {
                item.backsideVisible = !item.backsideVisible;
            }
        }))
    }

    return(
        <ProductList items={item} handleTurn={handleTurn}/>
    );
}
```

ProductList.js:

```
function ProductList(props) {
    return(
        <ul>
            <CardItem items={props.items} handleTurn={props.handleTurn} />
        </ul>
    );
}
```

CardItem.js

```
function CardItem(props) {
    return(
        {props.items.map(item =>(
            <li key={item.id} onClick={event => props.handleTurn(event, item.id)}>
                product-image etc...
            </li>
        ))}
        
    );
}
```

But everytime i try this, ill get an "TypeError: can't access property "id", item is undefined" error.
As soon as i change the handleTurn Method to something like

```
function handleTurn(event, itemId) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(itemId);
}
```

everything works fine and the console displays the id of the clicked item. So for me it seems, that my handleTurn Function has some errors.

Do you guys have any idea where my fault is?

Your help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you forgot to return `item` on each iteration. Also, you want to use the function signature of setState for this. Always use a snapshot of your state never the state itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `item` (which should really be called `items` since it's an array.  names matter) to an array of `undefined` elements, because your `map()` callback doesn't return anything:

```
setItem(item.map(item => {
    if(item.id === itemId) {
        item.backsideVisible = !item.backsideVisible;
    }
}))
```

Either return the updated object:

```
setItem(item.map(item => {
    if(item.id === itemId) {
        item.backsideVisible = !item.backsideVisible;
    }
    return item;
}))
```

or have the whole expression be a returned object:

```
setItem(item.map(item => ({
    ...item,
    backsideVisible: item.id === itemId ? !item.backsideVisible : item.backsideVisible
})));
```